# Disable Task Scheduler headless (silent) mode

Tags: java, windows, selenium-webdriver, scheduled-tasks

I have a Selenium WebDriver application (java) that i have scheduled to run daily through windows task scheduler. This application kicks off a browser based on its configuration and performs other task and so on. Presently, when i run the application using the scheduler, it runs in the background as silent or headless. When the application is done, it sends an email as expected. When i run the same application using command prompt, it launches the browser and all actions are visible on the screen. 
My question is how do i setup the scheduler to be able to launch the browser just as the command prompt so that i can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the scheduler it runs very similar like an service - which also can't launch a GUI.
When launched as a windows service you can configure it to allow interaction with the desktop.